# ng-repeat: filter on object property

Tags: json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

The following code is not correctly filtering the results:

```
<input placeholder="search" type="text" ng-model="q">
    <div ng-repeat="items in configuration.items | filter:{items.descr:q}">
      <div>
        <h3>{{items.descr}}</h3>
      </div>
```

Why? Actually this code is not working at all on this json object, `$configuration` :

```
{
    "descr": "Project - Configuration",
    "items": {
        "dangerous_components": {
            "descr": "Warning stuffs",
            "items": {
                "electrical_components": {
                    "descr": "electrical components here",
                    "values": [{
                        "key": "NOT_APPLICABLE",
                        "label": "N/A",
                        "svalue": null
                    }]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your json is not valid! Change <"items":{},> to <"items":{}>

Comment: On what do you want to filter? i.e. on which of the 3 `descr` attributes of the object tree?

Comment: @Ricky  Next time,be sure that your json object is valid you can use this site : jsonlint.com

Comment: I add the comma by mistake, my json is valid I can assure that.

Comment: @jb-nizet I wanna filter on the 2nd 'descr'

Comment: `items["dangerous_components"].descr` is the actual tree structure to get to `descr`. Or `items["electrical_components"].descr` depending on which set of items you working from. **not** items.descr as you have it in the filter